# Cut MultiPolygon layer with MultiLineString layer

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to remove the surface occupied by a polygon layer from a line layer.

That is to say, that the input layer corresponds to the polygon layer and the overlay layer (using the vector tool "cut" as an example) corresponds to the line layer.

With the vector tool "cut" it results in the opposite by giving me a layer of lines circumscribed to the layer of polygons, but my intention would be to eliminate the surface occupied by the layer of lines of the polygon layer.

How could I do such a thing?

Comment: Please ask your question in English.

Comment: Simply switch the two layers in the cutting/clipping tool.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is an English language forum. Please pass your text through translation software, and [Edit] the Question to include that. If you are worried about accuracy of translation, you can include both in the Question  body (though it may be removed later).

Comment: Sounds the *Difference* tool will do what you want. See [Vector overlays](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html) in the QGIS documentation.